# How to ASCII-armor my public key without installing GPG?

Tags: gnupg, public-key, public-key-encryption

I would like to upload my public key to a key server, but I already have my key infrastructure in place without GPG and I don't want to install extra software I don't need. Is there an easy way to ASCII-armor my public key without installing the whole GnuPG software suite?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OpenPGP's "Radix-64" ASCII armor, described in [RFC 4880 § 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-6), is mostly just standard Base64 with PEM-like begin/end headers, and with a CRC24 checksum at the end. It can be implemented like this:

1. Write the Armor Header Line; optional Armor Headers; and a blank line:

   ```
   -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
   Version: conradpgp v1.0
   (leave this line empty)
   ```
2. Write the Base64-encoded message, wrapped to 76 characters per line.
3. Write the checksum line, consisting of a `=` followed by the Base64-encoded Armor Checksum:

   > The checksum is a 24-bit Cyclic Redundancy Check (CRC) converted to
   > four characters of radix-64 encoding by the same MIME base64
   > transformation, preceded by an equal sign (=).  The CRC is computed
   > by using the generator 0x864CFB and an initialization of 0xB704CE.
   > The accumulation is done on the data before it is converted to
   > radix-64, rather than on the converted data.  A sample implementation
   > of this algorithm is [in the next section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-6.1).

   (See [section 6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-6.1) for the example CRC24 code.)
4. Finally, write the Armor Tail:

   ```
   -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
   ```

Comment: +1 for `conradpgp v1.0`.

Comment: See [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242143/how-to-get-v12-0-to-print-pgp-public-key-and-secret-key-blocks-after-generating).